# Why should we use inverse QFT instead of QFT in Shor's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

Why should we use inverse QFT instead of QFT in Shor's algorithm? When I tried to simulate Shor's algorithm for small numbers, I got an answer even when I used just QFT instead of inverse QFT.

Comment: How did you simulate the algorithm? Could you give the details?

Answer (score 9):

For Shor's algorithm, it actually doesn't matter which one you use.

If you apply the QFT twice, it is equivalent to a classical multiplication by -1 modulo $2^n$ where $n$ is the size of the register. That is to say, it reverses the order of all of the computational basis states except for $|0\rangle$ which stays where it started. $|k\rangle$ becomes $|-k\rangle = |2^n - k\rangle$.

Now, in Shor's algorithm, the output of the QFT is a state with amplitudes whose magnitudes are approximately periodic with a period that divides $2^n$. This isn't a coincidence; it's crucial to how the whole algorithm works. Because the period is a divisor of the number of computational basis states, reversing their order has a negligible effect on the state. Therefore there is little difference between using the QFT and the inverse QFT, because $\text{QFT}^{-1} = \text{QFT} \cdot \text{QFT}^{-1} \cdot \text{QFT}^{-1} = \text{QFT} \cdot \text{Mul}(-1)$.

[Example](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22~input%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22~guess%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setR%22%2C%22arg%22%3A55%7D%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setB%22%2C%22arg%22%3A26%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA10%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22*BToAmodR6%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT%E2%80%A010%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance10%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT10%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT10%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance10%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22~guess%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22guess%3A%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22~input%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22input%3A%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22~out%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22out%3A%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D):

[image: try both]

Note how the probability distributions are almost identical after an inverse QFT or after a QFT (in the above diagram the second qft is just to undo the inverse QFT). Since the output distribution is nearly identical the algorithm works either way.

Comment: Do you have a mathematical demonstration of this  |⟩  becomes |−⟩=|2^−⟩? If you apply the QFT twice, it is equivalent to a classical multiplication by -1 modulo 2
 where  is the size of the register. That is to say, it reverses the order of all of the computational basis states except for |0⟩, which stays where it started. |⟩  becomes |−⟩=|2^−⟩.

Comment: @ParfaitAtchadé https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT6%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT6%22%5D%5D%7D

Comment: many thanks for the quirk. I understand the scheme. I would like to understand the demonstration of QFT(QFT)|x> = |-x>. Do you have the demonstration? Many thanks.